# How to split a table by two columns in FastReport?

Tags: fastreport

I have a typical FastReport report with a table inside of a MasterData band. The table is pretty lengthy and narrow, so I'm thinking about splitting it in half and placing the lower half next to the upper half like so:

```
A        A  D
B        B  E
C   ->   C  F
D
E
F
```

There's a catch - rows on the table are 1-3 lines tall.

I have tried using MasterData.Columns property. Two problems with it are: it splits the table by-row, making it AB CD EF, which is not acceptable, also it does not account for row heights, so if for example row A is taller than others, then there's unwanted gap after D on the second column (despite the `StretchMode = smMaxHeight`).

My FastReport version is 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

FastReport has two ways to make a column report.

You already discovered one of them "band columns" - this method prints band from left to right and then down.

The second way is a page columns.
With Page column FR prints band till the end of the page and then moves to next column. I think this method exactly what you are looking for.
To make a page columns just double click on the page in the report designer, select other options tab and set the number of columns you want to print.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, but is there a way to account for variable-height rows, so if ABC rows are 5cm each and DEF rows are just 1cm, the split is made like AB/CDEF. ?

Comment: You have to set "Double Pass" in report options and in first pass calculate heights and fill for example in the list (like Add(band line, height on the page)). At the second pass you have to look in filled values and if height is too big call Report.Engine.NewColumn method.